# Font Awesome randomly not showing icons, with nothing changed

Tags: css, href, font-awesome

I have had the Font Awesome icons connected and working with a new site design I am building. I have checked the href for the file and most other things that would change this. It just randomly stopped working yesterday, even if I link directly to the CSS file on the server and not the CDN it will not show up. It also throws no error.

Anyone else have this issue or similar issues?

Link I was using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css">
```

Comment: did you update that link from version 3.2.1 recently maybe? the old font awesome has totally different classes for rendering icons: http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/

Comment: Yes, I try to update it a month or so after they update their CDN.

Comment: what's your <i></i> tags like to render the icons? paste an example icon not showing up with that link tag in your <head> section

Comment: my class for each icon is this format "fa fa-search fa-fw" and usually if the icons don't show up it shows a little square in its place, but for some reason they are not showing at all when I inspect in the browser. I will inspect again and see if I missed something.

Comment: inspect the <i> and see if there's a display:none or something. that must be something else then font awesome

Comment: I would also check the console to make sure the font is returning something other than a 200 request. Although based on what you said it sounds like it is being served.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue with font-awesome failing to load that involved my DNS host last year. We had 2 domains (www.companycorp.com, www.companycorporation.com) pointing to one server. The site had the font-awesome URL as www.companycorp.com/... , and it would randomly fail to load the font-awesome icons on www.companycorporation.com. The solution was to just redirect www.companycorporation.com to www.companycorp.com.

Is your DNS setup in a similar manner? Can you provide a link to your site?

Comment: I actually use the CDN to connect to the CSS, but this is making me think twice, especially when we move this test site to production.

Comment: Just to follow up: I've run into this issue numerous times, over different sites (really recently). I don't know if the .htaccess are being set by the folder containing to default 'deny access' to external sites, but the result is I always just give it a relative path from the root (/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css) and that fixes the problem.